# For each pair of functions f1 and f2 in (a) - (h) below, provide functions h1

Tags: discrete-mathematics, algorithms, computer-science, computational-complexity

**For each pair of functions f1 and f2 in (a) - (h) below, provide functions h1 and h2 such that
f1 = Θ(h1) and f2 = Θ(h2). The functions h1 and h2 should be in one of the following forms: n
k
logp n
or a
n
k logp n
for some fixed non-negative k and p and for some fixed a > 1. In each case, you have to
provide concrete values of a, k and p that work. Give a detailed justification of your answers for functions
in (b), (e), (f).**

[image]

Can someone tell me if I'm even doing this correctly? I haven't dealt with TCs in while.
So I got:

$a) h_1(n) = O(n) \implies n$ , $h_2(n) = \Omega (n\log n) \implies n\log n$

$b) h_1(n) = \Omega(\log n) \implies \log n$, $h_2(n) = O(n^{2/5}) \implies n^{2/5}$

(Justification$h_1(n)$: Let $n = 1000 \implies 12(1000)^{2/3} = 524$ and Let $x = 1000 \implies 7 \log(1000) = 48$ so $n^{2/5} > \log(n)$)

(Justification$h_2(n)$: Let $n = 1000 \implies (5(100000000))^{2/5} = 3017.08..$ so $n^{2/5} > O(1)$  (or 1000) )

$c) h_1(n) = O(n^2) \implies n^2$, $h_2(n) = \Omega(n \log^4 n) \implies n \log^4 n$

$d) h_1(n) = O(\log(n)) \implies \log(n)$, $h_2(n) = \Omega (\log(n^5)) \implies \log(n^5)$

$e) h_1(n) = O(n) \implies n$, $h_2(n) = O(n) \implies n$

(Justification$h_1(n)$: let $n = 1000 \implies 1000^{1.02} = 1148.15 > \log(1000)^{1.02} = 7.17..$)

(Justification$h_2(n)$: let $n = 1000$ to find $1000(1000)log^3 1000 = 3.296.. < 2(1000) = 2000$)

$f) h_1(n) = O(n^2) \implies n^2$, $h_2(n) = \Omega(\log n) \implies \log n$

(Justification$h_1(n)$: Well $O(n^2) = n^2$ ?)

(Justification$h_2(n)$: $O(\log n) = \log n$) ?

$h) h_1(n) = O(n) \implies n$, $h_2(n) =$ exponential?

Comment: & I'm guessing no one has any idea. Great.

Comment: Do you mean one of the following forms: $n^klog_pn$ or $an^klog_pn$?

Comment: First, the various Big-O notations were built to make constants irrelevant, so in this case, $ank(log_p(n)) = \Theta(n\log(n))$. So changing constants won't change any Big-O relationships. Are you sure you've copied the question correctly? Could the intention have been to allow the thetas ($\Theta$) to vary between $O$, $\Theta$, or $\Omega$?